# How to use Windows Explorer File Browser on PowerBuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm using a PictureListBox to display some thumbnails for picture preview. The pictures I have listed there were added on development for testing purposes. The final product must give the user an option to import pictures manually.

The question is: How can I access Windows File Explorer to open pictures manually?

First thing I noticed when I googled about this issue was that there aren't many resources regarding powerbuilder on the web. I found the same question with an answer on a StackOverflow wannabe site, but the solution was only avaliable for paying subscribers only.

I'm feeling like this is pretty simple to deal with but since I'm a total noob with powerbuilder, go easy on me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: BTW, the answers on the other site show up on Google because they're all the way at the bottom. Otherwise Google wouldn't have seen them.

Comment: A lot of the PowerBuilder Q&A have been hosted on USENET, not on the web (long history, move to web delayed by SAP acquisition). For instructions to access: http://www.sybase.com/support/community-forums. Google Groups used to index them, but they've stopped, so the content you can find searching from there is a little aged. This will likely get merged into the SAP community infrastructure soon, so this information will hopefully be soon outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is: How can I access Windows File Explorer to open pictures manually?

You may be looking for `GetFileOpenName()` that opens the "open file" system dialog to chose a file.

Comment: @ShikStylko: you're welcome to ask questions concerning PB! The PB section of the [Real's HowTo](http://www.rgagnon.com/howto.html) might be helpful also. But don't trust paying technical sites like Experts-Exchange :o)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I came from C# and skipping lines without ";" is really bugging me. Not to mention the "PB IDE's layout of doom". I think I'll take some time till I get used to this.

Once again, thanks for your help mate. :)

Comment: @ShikStylko: In PB, the semicolon is a statement delimiter (when you want to place several statements on the same line - e.g. to shorten a `choose case` notation). So it is valid to have one at the end of a line, if you feel comfortable with it ^_^

Comment: I made the mistake of re-inventing the wheel some time in my PB career and later learned of GetFileOpenName() which is awesome.